# How to use chains without applying anti-patterns in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, prototype, chain

If you try to program in a functional style on JavaScript, you'll probably realize the conventional `fn(obj,params...)` form gets unreadable fast.

```
console.log(
    join(
        map(function(row){ return row.join(" "); },
            format(
                map(function(text){return align(text},
                    view),
                20))),
    "\n");
```

VS

```
view.map(function(text){return align(text)})
    .format(20)
    .map(function(row){return row.join(" ");})
    .join("\n")
    .log();
```

Problematically, the latter style could only be implemented extending the `Object.prototype` with new functions, which is globally regarded as **evil**. Yet, the readability is so superior that I'm prompted to just go ahead and do it anyway. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way to solve the problem.  Below is a demonstration using [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

Bad method:

```
import _ from "lodash";

_.chain([1, 2, 3])
  .map(x => [x, x*2])
  .flatten()
  .sort()
  .value();
```

Better method:

```
import map from "lodash/fp/map";
import flatten from "lodash/fp/flatten";
import sortBy from "lodash/fp/sortBy";
import flow from "lodash/fp/flow";

flow(
  map(x => [x, x*2]),
  flatten,
  sortBy(x => x) 
)([1,2,3]);
```

See [Why using `_.chain` is a mistake.](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba#.ni9g5zsgm) for a fantastic, in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A common "monadic" approach to this is to wrap an operand into your own object, call a chain of methods on that object and then extract the plain value back. Example from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) docs:

```
var youngest = _.chain(stooges)
  .sortBy(function(stooge){ return stooge.age; })
  .map(function(stooge){ return stooge.name + ' is ' + stooge.age; })
  .first()
  .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic pattern is

1. Create a constructor function, store the object's state as properties on `this`
2. Add your chainable methods to the constructor's prototype. In the body of these functions, alter the object's state attached to `this`, then return `this`.
3. Provide a method to use at the end of the chain to convert from your custom chainable object to a raw array or whatever the non-chainable analog is.

http://jsfiddle.net/XjRrn/ is a working example:

```
function ChainableArray(rawArray) {
     this._array = rawArray || [];
};
ChainableArray.prototype.map = function(fn) {
    this._array = _.map(this._array, fn);
    return this;
};
ChainableArray.prototype.incr = function(amount) {
    this._array = _.map(this._array, function (item) {return item + amount;});
    return this;
};
ChainableArray.prototype.toArray = function () {
    return _.clone(this._array);
};
```

[The Query object from the mongoose.js library](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/query.js) is a great case study to reference.